# Redis requests slowing down significantly when receiving multiple requests

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cache

I am currently working on my school project, which is a research about the performance of Redis Cache. The use case is a webshop with different amount of products (1.000/5.000/12.500/25.000). I am measuring the response time with different kind of scenario's, for example: show 50 products, 100 products or 200 products. Each product is about 1.5 kB big.

The problem I am currently experiencing is that my Redis clogs up after receiving more than a few requests. The first request is done in 90 msec, the second one is done in about 140 msec, after that it starts going up times 2 (200, 400, 800, etc) up until 2000 msec.

I save all my products individually and do 50 to 200 single requests at once to retrieving the products (in JSON). I have tried pipelining, batching and saving all the products under one key. None of these solutions is good for my performance.

I experience this problem on my localhost and in Azure.

What's the best practice in my kind of situation for saving and retrieving products with up to 250 concurrent users retrieving those products at once?

Thank you!
Thomas

Comment: Hi Thomas, be great if you can add some code to your question. Take a look at the wiki for creating minimal, complete, verifiable examples - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you using [MGET](https://redis.io/commands/mget) to retrieve the keys? That command scales O(N) with the number of keys requested. Additionally, there is overhead for each separate request on the network and larger responses will always take longer than smaller responses.